# Using awk for vlookup functionality in bash script

Tags: awk, vlookup

Here are the input:

> files1.csv

```
21|AAAAA|1023
21|BBBBB|1203
21|CCCCC|2533
22|DDDDD|1294
22|EEEEE|1249
22|FFFFF|4129
22A|GGGGG|4121
22A|HHHHH|1284
31B|IIIII|5403
31B|JJJJJ|1249
```

> file2.csv

```
21|A800
22|B900
22A|C1000
31B|D1000
```

expect output:

> files3.csv

```
21|A800|AAAAA|1023
21|A800|BBBBB|1203
21|A800|CCCCC|2533
22|B900|EEEEE|1249
22|B900|FFFFF|4129
22A|C1000|GGGGG|4121
22A|C1000|HHHHH|1284
31B|D1000|IIIII|5403
31B|D1000|JJJJJ|1249
```

currently tried using join,

```
join -a1 -t '|' -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.2,1.3 file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

But it found that some rows missed matching, so i turn my concept to use most likely vlookup functionality for this two files. Please help.

Thanks all

Comment: Seems like the row containing `DDDDD` is missing in the expected output. Not sure if that's intentional? Otherwise your `join` command seems to work...

Comment: on a side node, it is `files1` and `files3` but only `file2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following with `awk`, written and tested with GNU `awk` with shown samples.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in arr){
  $1=($1 OFS arr[$1])
}
1
' file2.csv file1.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                 ##Starting BEGIN section from here of this program.
  FS=OFS="|"           ##Setting | as field separator and output field separator.
}
FNR==NR{               ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2.csv is being read.
  arr[$1]=$2           ##Creating arr with index of 1st field and value of 2nd field.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr){           ##checking condition if $1 is present in arr then do following.
  $1=($1 OFS arr[$1])  ##Saving current $1 OFS and value of arr with index of $1 in $1.
}
1                      ##1 will print the current line.
' file2.csv file1.csv  ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the `join` command you provided and I think it produces the intended output on my machine (FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE):

```
21|A800|AAAAA|1023
21|A800|BBBBB|1203
21|A800|CCCCC|2533
22|B900|DDDDD|1294
22|B900|EEEEE|1249
22|B900|FFFFF|4129
22A|C1000|GGGGG|4121
22A|C1000|HHHHH|1284
31B|D1000|IIIII|5403
31B|D1000|JJJJJ|1249
```

It's possible that you need to sort both files first on the columns (or in this case where you join the first columns the whole line should also work) that you intend to join, i.e. `join -a1 -t '|' -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.2,1.3 <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) > file3.csv`